# ionic firebase data appears in the template after a few seconds

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

When ı run app and click notifications data appears in the template after a 10-15 seconds.
I checked the data with the console log when I was pulling datas, datas are coming normally(fast), the problem is that it shows late in HTML.

When I enter the notifications page :  https://prnt.sc/11dtqkj

After waiting for 10-15 seconds :
https://prnt.sc/11dttn4

How can ı fix this problem ?

**notifications.page.ts :**

```
 ionViewWillEnter(){
        this.auth.currentUser.then(user=>{
          
          this.userUid = user.uid
       this.db.database.ref("/users/"+user.uid+"/notifications/").once("value",snap=>{this.notifications=[],snap.forEach(a=>{
         
         this.db.database.ref("/users/"+a.child("who").val()+"/name").once("value",a2=>{let temp_a=a;
    
           this.db.database.ref("/users/"+temp_a.child("who").val()+"/pp").once("value",a3=>{let temp_a2=temp_a; let a2_name = a2.val();
    
    
             let type = temp_a2.child("type").val();
             let not_key = temp_a2.key;
             let name = a2_name;
             let pp = a3.val();
             let who = temp_a2.child("who").val();
             let formId = temp_a2.child("formId").val();
             let result = temp_a2.child("result").val();
             
             if(type=="request"){
                this.notifications.push({notKey:not_key,type:type,name: name,pp:pp,who:who,formId:formId});
              }
              else if(type=="response"){
                 this.notifications.push({type:type,name:name,pp:pp,who:who,result:result});
              }
           })
         });
         })
        })
       })
      }
```

**notifications.page.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>Bildirimler</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
 <ion-list >
   <div *ngFor="let item of notifications;let i index ">
   <ion-item *ngIf="item.type=='request'">
    <ion-avatar slot="start">
      <img src={{item.pp}}>
    </ion-avatar>
     <ion-label style="white-space: pre-wrap;"><strong>{{item.name}}:</strong>adlı kullanıcı beraber kamp yapmak istiyor.</ion-label>
     <ion-label><ion-button (click)="accept(item.who,item.formId,item.notKey,i)" style="width: 50%;" color="secondary"><ion-icon name="checkmark-outline"></ion-icon></ion-button>
                <ion-button (click)="reject(item.who,item.notKey,item.formId,i)" color="light"><ion-icon name="close-outline"></ion-icon></ion-button></ion-label>
   </ion-item>
   <ion-item *ngIf="item.type=='response'">
    <ion-avatar slot="start">
      <img src={{item.pp}}>
    </ion-avatar>
    <ion-label style="white-space: pre-wrap;"><strong>{{item.name}}:</strong>adlı kullanıcı tarafından katılma isteğiniz {{item.result}}</ion-label>
   </ion-item>
  </div>
 </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
```

Comment: Did you try to put the code in ngOnInit ? Why in ionViewWillEnter ?

Comment: @PatrickCiseran I tried the same result

Comment: Are you using angularfire library ? Or the firebase sdk ?

Comment: @PatrickCiseran Angular fire library

Comment: I had this issue once when using  realtime db (I use firestore now).
Can&#39;t remember where the issue was. 
Maybe if you search the angularfire GitHub issues, you&#39;ll find.
Are you sure to have the latest version?

Comment: @PatrickCiseran My fire version is 6.1.2 latest version is 6.1.4  Does it matter ?

Comment: Yes it might solve, not certain but it's the first step.

Comment: where did you put your console logs and it what order are they displayed ?

Comment: @PatrickCiseran https://prnt.sc/11hziuq   It's happening pretty quickly.

Comment: Did you try ion-img ?
Or suppress as many elements as possible just to check if it's coming from the view ?

Comment: @PatrickCiseran I tried ion-img but  didn't work

Comment: @PatrickCiseran problems in images  when ı remove user's pp its work normally

Comment: Where do you store images?

Comment: Firebase storage